# How can I use java configuration of spring batch without spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, configuration, spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch and I'm trying to learn about it.
I implemented datasource and batch configuration but it doesn't seem to work, because

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '$tableName.batch_job_instance' doesn't exist
```

DataSourceConfiguration class :

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() throws SQLException {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/task4");
        dataSource.setUsername("name");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And I have Batch configuration class, but I dont know @EnableBatchProcessing annotation works without springboot

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(DataSourceConfiguration.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<User> itemReader() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<User>()
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .name("creditReader")
                .sql("select userLogin, userEmail, userPassword, accountBalance from userInfo")
                .rowMapper(new UserRowMapper())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<User> simpleItemWriter(){
        return new SimpleUserWriter();
    }
    @Bean
    public Job sampleJob() {
        return this.jobs.get("sampleJob")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return this.steps.get("step1")
                .<User,User>chunk(10)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(simpleItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Main class contains those lines of code :

```
 public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BatchConfiguration.class);
        context.getBean("jobRepository");
        JobLauncher jobLauncher =  context.getBean("jobLauncher",JobLauncher.class);
        Job job =  context.getBean("sampleJob", Job.class);
        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : "+ execution.getStatus());

        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Job ExamResult failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to say that you are missing the tables needed by Spring batch.

Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/schema-appendix.html

You can also find SQL files ready for the different DB engine under `org/springframework/bacth/core/schema-<DB>.sql` in the spring batch core jar file